# App.config in Window service

Tags: c#, service, c#-2.0, app-config

I am in the process of designing a Windows Service, Where i have App.config. When the service is running i am not able to change the config values. But those values are not getting reflected. when it reades next time.

Is it manadatory to restart service eveyr time we change config values?

Do you have any suggestion how we can do this with out implementing some kind of file watch ?

Answer (score 0):

You can reload configuration programatically with Reload():

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
```